# Access Azure Resources from Azure Pipeline Tasks without principal

Tags: azure, entra-id, amazon-codepipeline

I have an MSDN subscription from my company with some monthly credit. My company also uses AzureAD and its services for user management in our company. For that reason I cannot create a principal on my own to access the resources I created in this subscription. Is there another way of accessing things like KeyVault for example from the pipeline tasks, other than a principal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use the azure command line interface to login directly with your account?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I did not think of it. It's is not as convenient to use as the predefined tasks but it does it's job.